# Retrofit 2 prints empty response body in log with HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use `Retrofit 2.0.0`. This is the code that builds my HTTP client

```
protected OkHttpClient getHttpClient(){
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(
                chain -> {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();

                    requestBuilder.header("Accept-Language", App.getInstance().getPrefs().getSelectedLanguage().toLowerCase());
                    requestBuilder.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

                    if(API.this instanceof PrivateAPI){
                        LoginResponse loginResponse = AuthManager.getInstanse().getLoginResponse();
                        requestBuilder.header("Authorization", String.format("%s %s",
                                loginResponse.getTokenType(),
                                loginResponse.getAccessToken()));
                    }

                    requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                });

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
```

And here is how I use it to init my Retrofit API interface:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(getHttpClient())
            .build();

    apiService = retrofit.create(PrivateAPIInterface.class);
```

Until yesterday I was getting full log in logcat as it supposed to be. But suddenly I begin to get empty response bodies in my log. So here is an example of log I get now:

```
  D/OkHttp: --> GET http://MY_DOMAIN/utility/gaz?branchid=&phone=21919&customerid= HTTP/1.1
  D/OkHttp: Accept-Language: hy
  D/OkHttp: Accept-Encoding: gzip
  D/OkHttp: Authorization: 0yXK65Go_hRPT32WIP4DAKjmzIaM0riSLlybHhusvwmYJSxTdTVBrkL5CaqopXgrOuNFL5xvR5uVwCbprWrxvfYTMJ1I_AUmd5TKdNL4ptkUrJuOy1kGiule_yveCFv0GbTiAXhYjdfynJICJEVWc54ibnIv_Q14dLpPuVle5IaRuHmza2Pavkrhzi42sfMsK0Qpxaueu8eRPysk6MP9WkTnSKYIAThuq3sHq8RGAnkaLBx
  D/OkHttp: --> END GET
  D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://MY_DOMAIN/utility/gaz?branchid=&phone=21919&customerid= (394ms)
  D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 8527
  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 12:30:37 GMT
  D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1458131438086
  D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1458131438438
  D/OkHttp: }
  D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (8527-byte body)
```

As you can see everything I get instead of response body is `D/OkHttp: }`.
But in Postman I see a normal response body and in my app everything works fine so the problem is only with logging.

Can anybody help me to understand why this can start happening?

P.S. In case of requests that has body I see the request body the problem is only with response bodys.

Answer (score 6):

With retrofit-2 you are supposed to use **OkHttp3** for getting full logs. Add this to your dependecies: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'`

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

return retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);
```

Comment: I have it - compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0', before I tried compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'  too... it does not work

Comment: You are passing `getHttpClient()` in the retrofit builder. Instead of that you are supposed to pass the OkHttpClient(refer line 3 of my answer). I have tried this it gives complete logs and works fine.
Use it the way I have posted you need not create function for getHttpClient().

Comment: getHttpClient() does exactly the same thing that you do, but also has extra logic in it. Anyways I tries the way you suggested and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

ResClient.class

```
 public class RestClient {

        private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

        static {
            setupRestClient();
        }

        private static void setupRestClient() {
            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                      .setEndpoint(NetworkConstants.URL_BASE_LIVE)
                                      .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                                      .setLog(new AndroidLog("Retrofit"))
                                      .setClient(new OkClient(httpClient))
                                      .build();

            apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }


        public static ApiInterface getAdapter(){
                return apiInterface;
        }
    }
```

ApiInterface.class

```
public interface ApiInterface {


    // result api
    //All result api async
    @Headers({"Authorization: ######################"}) //for the header authorization if needed.
    @GET(NetworkConstants.URL_GET_RESULTS)
    void getResult(@QueryMap Map <String, String> params, Callback<ArrayList<Results>> callback);
}
```

Now call it like

```
// Fetching result through Api Hit   
        RestClient.getAdapter().getResult(getJobsParams(), new Callback<ArrayList<Result>>() {

            @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<Result> result, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                   // Do your Work
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                   // show server or other error to user
            }
        });
```

Comment: The answer you gave is for Retrofit 1, mine is Retrofit 2