# retrofit2 HttpLoggingInterceptor response body log is incorrect

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

this is my interceptor

```
.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
                @Override
                public void log(String message) {
                    LogUtil.d(message);
                }
            }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
```

my build.gridle is

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

when I post api,the log is below:

```
05-16 16:49:00.796 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: --> POST http://test.blhsc.com/api/resetPass.ashx http/1.1
05-16 16:49:00.796 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
05-16 16:49:00.796 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Content-Length: 183
05-16 16:49:00.797 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: {"systemVersion":"23","session":"","appVersion":"1","deviceTime":"1463388540788","deviceType":"2","account":"15980253327","deviceModel":"MI 4LTE","newPass":"123456","accountType":"0"}
05-16 16:49:00.797 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: --> END POST (183-byte body)
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: <-- 200 OK http://test.blhsc.com/api/resetPass.ashx (428ms)
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Cache-Control: private
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Content-Length: 73
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 08:49:03 GMT
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1463388540799
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1463388541225
                                                    }   --> this line is incorrect
05-16 16:49:01.226 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: <-- END HTTP (73-byte body)
```

the question is the same to [Retrofit 2 prints empty response body in log with HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035943/retrofit-2-prints-empty-response-body-in-log-with-httplogginginterceptor-level-b)

this is question is bore me a week.I am crazy now.please help me.thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cry.This is question is not in retrofit2.But android studio's bug.When I use adb logcat -s 'your tag',I can see the all info.

Answer (score 1):

Try to develop your Interceptor like this:

```
public class AppUtil {
public static final boolean isEnableLogging = true;
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if(isEnableLogging)
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        else
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.URL_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your web service if it is properly built or not.